# How to use multiple jquery version so that ResponsiveSlides.js works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

My website uses jquery version 1.11.o and I would like to use ResponsiveSlides.js from GitHub to show a slideshow on my home page but ResponsiveSlides.js uses jquery version 1.8.3 and it conflicts with v1.11.0 so my site breaks.

I have tried the solution below that I found in another question so that I can use both jquery version but it didn't work. How can I accomplish this and use both jquery versions without conflict?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>var $j = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   console.log($().jquery); // This prints v1.11.0
   console.log($j().jquery); // This prints v1.8.3
  });
```

Comment: try an iframe --- http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp

Comment: An iframe in <head>? I don't think that's possible.

Comment: make sure you read all about what an iframe is before you speculate hat it goes in the head

Comment: I know what an iframe is but the jquery needs to go in the head tag and an iframe will not work there, thus, your solution isn't helpful but thanks

Comment: create a separate html page for your ResponsiveSlides and add the jquery version there in the head. then use an iframe to display the ResponsiveSlides  page in the main page. should look  ok

Answer (score 0):

Using 2 versions of jQuery is not recommended and will cause a load of problems. You should use the [jQuery migrate plugin](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.3.0.min.js). The plugin restores deprecated features and behaviors so that older code will still run properly on jQuery 1.9 and later. The latest versions would be used like this:

```
<script src="jquery-1.12.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-migrate-1.3.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```